# Impact of runtime allocation beyond initial overhead

Tags: c, performance, memory, fortran

I'm aware that if you have compile-time variable initialisations, the program will run faster than run-time initialisation because memory needs to be allocated dynamically.

My question is: does dynamically-allocated memory have a long-term impact on program performance beyond the initial allocation overhead? Is it more expensive to access dynamic memory? My question is specifically about Fortran but it's probably also relevant to C etc.

So, if I had some initial command-line arguments to initialise the sizes of a bunch of arrays to begin a computation, would it significantly slow down the program as compared to setting that argument as a constant parameter and recompiling each time I wanted to compute with different-sized arrays?

Comment: What about "Is it less expensive to access dynamic memory?"  Consider a _large_ static array, each element  initialized to 1 vs. a large dynamic array , elements assigned to 1.  Which file is smaller?  The large static array size may take more time to _load_ than `malloc()` and `memcpy()` takes to run.  Better to post an example, else this is just  theoretical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is largely system dependent. It is possible that there are systems that can optimize static data better than dynamic memory. In the days before the FORTRAN committee went insane with the FORTRADA 90 abomination, FORTRAN was all static. It was common for FORTRAN compilers even to use static call frames. There is some theoretical potential for better performance with all static.

That said, once dynamic memory is allocated, it is going to be highly unlikely that accessing it will be slower than accessing static data in nearly all cases.